# c# Make a variable value "" on button click, but only to the dialog box

Tags: c#, .net, permissions

I have a modeless UI that adds a userID to a list that allows or removes access to parts of a program. When I click the modify button everything works as it should. Suppose I close the dialog and realize "Wait, forgot to do X". When I reopen the dialog box, perform my work and click Modify, the value for adding the userID is still available to the program even though the textbox is blank.

It's happening somewhere in the following code.

```
public static void checkSame()
{
    int count = 0;
    bool test = false;

    while (linesPerm.Length >= count && tbPermValue != "")
    {
        if (linesPerm.Length >= count)
        {
            test = linesPerm.Contains(tbPermValue);
            count += (linesPerm.Length + 1);

            if (test == true)
            {
               DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("The UserID " + tbPermValue + 
               " already exists in the Permissions column. " 
                    + Environment.NewLine + "Would you like to add the UserID" + 
                    tbPermValue + " to the Permissions column anyway?", 
                    "User Already Exists", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                switch (dr)
                {
                    case DialogResult.Yes:
                        break;

                    case DialogResult.No:
                        tbPermValue = "";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Do Nothing");
        }
    }
}
```

If the user selects No on the dialog box, the value of `tbPermValue` is not available to the program. If the user selects Yes then the value of `tbPermValue` persists even if the dialog box is closed and reopened. I have tried to clear the textbox value like so.

```
tbUserName.Text = "";
tbUserName.Clear();
```

and several other ways. `tbUserName` value is being cleared from the textbox, but not from the code above. I get the value of `tbPermValue` like this.

```
public static void addPerm(System.Windows.Forms.Form targetForm)
{
    foreach (Control C in targetForm.Controls)
    {
        if (C.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            if (C.Text != "")
            {
                tbPermValue = C.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a modeless dialog box owned by it's parent.

Can anyone point me in a direction that would remove access to `tbPermValue` to the DialogResult portion of the first code box after the button is clicked. I can't lose it completely because `tbPermValue` is used in other code down the line.

EDIT: Ok. I just tested this and the value is being held in memory. I have a dialog Form1 that has a button that opens dialog StartHere. On StartHere there is a button that opens Permissions. StartHere owns Permissions so that when I close StartHere, Permissions and all other child forms of StartHere will close. These are all modeless dialogs. My variable tbPermValue is being held in memory way back to Form1. The value is not being disposed when I close the dialog StartHere. I'm going to go back and research Garbage Collection at the advice of Eric below. Thank you Eric. I'll delete the question or at least post a new better question once I find out the rules for this process. Thank You.

Edit 2: Here is the code you asked for γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε

```
    private void bModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WidgetLogic.addPerm(this);
        WidgetLogic.checkSame();
        WidgetLogic.writePerm(this);
        WidgetLogic.writeAdmin(this);
        WidgetLogic.writeDetailer(this);
        tbUserName.Clear();


    }
```

As noted above I have tried numerous ways to clear `tbUserName` to no avail.

Comment: I've read this several times and ***still*** don't know what you're asking?

Comment: @jbutler483 once a button is clicked and the check for duplicates is made, the textbox is cleared but the value passed to tbPermValue persists. I need it for other parts of the program. When the Modify button is clicked the value for tbPermValue from the textbox should be empty. The previously keyed value is still available. Even if I close and reopen the dialog the value remains available with an empty textbox.

Comment: I did not voted down and will never do it. But honestly, your code seems to be really not clear. Have ever think using binding and MVVM. It is not simple but believe me, it could solve a lots of problem and in final it is simpler to maintain.

Comment: @EricOuellet I don't mind the down votes. I think it would be helpful if they left comments though, which you did. Two comments that somethings not clear. What I'm asking and Cleaner code. That at lease tells me something. I could give a hoot if it got 1000 down votes. But if I got 1000 comments I could see what others are seeing :-D That in turn might help me to ask differently in the future.

Comment: Ok, make it **exactly clear**. You have a text box entry. When someone enters a value and presses 'enter' (for example), this value is checked against (`something?`). If it is present, a message box appears asking ('Its a duplicate. Continue anyway?') If they say yes (`doSomething`). If they say no (`doSomethingElse`). Could you clarify what you want the bits i've placed as code are meant to do, and if there's another bit to do afterwards?

Comment: @jbutler483 `doSomething` adds the userID to the list and should no longer be available to that portion of the program if the Modify button is clicked again. `doSomethingElse` works as it should. As it stands now `doSomething` does add the userID to the list but its previous value is still available if the textbox is blank and the user clicks the Modify button again. That should not happen.

Comment: By the sounds of it, you need a bool flag to test if the value is the same as previous entered.

Comment: If you want to verify against a set a already used values. I would personally used a Set (which is a collection of unique value). I personally use http://powercollections.codeplex.com/. I would add new value in it as needed. If it is Multithreaded, then I would use a ConcurrentDictionary using only the key. Good luck :-) !

Comment: @jbutler483 I get that, but I don't think that's the problem. What I mean to say is that if I were to close the dialog box, which does Dispose(); when leaving, and reopen the dialog box by a button selection, the value is still available to the program? I don't get it??

Comment: @EricOuellet Thank You. I'll check that out today. Looks like it might help.

Comment: If the value is still there it's because it never has been GC and you are re-using the same dialog. You could also clear the value in the Oninitialize or OnLoad event but if you need to do so it is because you have a deeper problem somewhere.

Comment: @EricOuellet I'm not sure that I have done proper garbage collection when the form is closed and reopened. That's true. This is a modeless form owned by it's parent. That way when I close the parent form, all child forms are disposed. It may be that the variable is being passed back to the parent form and being held in memory there. Wow. It's being held in memory. I just tested it and it goes way back. I will definitely begin looking at garbage collection now. Thank You very much. WOW!! :-D Please see edit for more.

Comment: Garbage collector and all these things are nonsense. When a value goes out of scope you can't access it. A global variable remains until the main form closes. Post the code in the *button click* to solve the issue.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε Posted in about a minute in the EDIT n: Oh Boy!! It's on now. :-D Thank you for coming to help. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `tbPermValue` but instead use the `textbox` directly:

```
while (linesPerm.Length >= count && tbUserName.Text != "")
```

**EDIT**

Change the code in `addPerm` to this, and you are done :):

```
public static void addPerm(System.Windows.Forms.Form targetForm)
{
    foreach (Control C in targetForm.Controls)
    {
        if (C.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            tbPermValue = C.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need the `switch (dr)` in `checkSame()`

Comment: I don't have access to `tbUserName`. It is passed to my logic file from the UI. Thank You for commenting though.

Comment: FRACKING BRILLIANT!! :-D I'm off to my real job. I will definitely step through this to try to see how you fixed it. MY HERO!! :-D Thank you very much!!

Comment: Ok. I see it. When I added `tbUserName.Clear();` to Permissions I did the right thing by clearing the field, but it did not pass `""` to the string 'tbPermValue'. Because it still held the userID it skipped over passing the new empty string to `tbPermValue` from `C.Text`. Thanks Again!! :-D

Answer (score 1):

I see that you say you have tried setting the following in the "yes" part of your switch statement:

```
tbUserName.Text = "";
tbUserName.Clear();
```

But in your "no" part, you don't set `tbUserName`, but instead you set the variable `tbPermValue`. From what I can tell, you should also be setting

```
tbPermValue = "";
```

in your "yes" part as well to clear that variable, or even just move it out of the switch and have it do that before the dialog closes since you would be setting it in all of the possible switch cases anyways.

Comment: Thank you for helping. `tbUserName` is found on the dialog Permissions while `tbPermValue` is assigned the value `tbUserName` from the `targetForm` Permissions. I clear `tbUserName` inside of the button_click method on the form Permissions.

Comment: Oh, I suppose you should use a flag then, but instead if testing against a previous value as jbutler483 suggested, I would use the DialogResult property. Then, in your addPerm method in your innermost if, you could test against both c.Text != "" and DialogResult == true, where if DialogResult is true when the user clicks yes, then you know to ignore tbPermValue = C.Text. Of course, as Eric Ouellet has now made clear to you (and I!), the real problem here is garbage collection.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a flag? I'm also confused as to why selecting No on the MessageBox clears the value being held in memory?

Comment: I elucidated on using a flag a little further just after you posted your comment, hopefully it anwsered that question a little bit better. And as far as why selecting no works...beats me, although I'm guessing it has something to do with the line tbPermValue = "";